# R: Select samples of items while controlling for differences on a number of variables

Tags: r, selection, sampling

I have a dataset with a list of words belonging to 3 groups (A, H or V) and 2 continuous variables (word length and word frequency):

```
mydata = structure(list(word = c("elastisch", "rutschig", "verklebt", 
"dumpf", "hallend", "formbar", "gelb", "braun", "blond", "klebrig", 
"blass", "blendend", "schlaff", "bunt", "singend", "lauwarm", 
"strahlend", "biegsam", "durchsichtig", "verbal", "erleuchtet", 
"schrill", "erloschen", "dehnbar", "beige", "farbig", "gepunktet", 
"heiser", "musikalisch", "schweigend", "schreiend", "schwer", 
"transparent", "flackernd", "blinkend", "stumpf", "gedimmt", 
"lautlos", "gefleckt", "pappig", "feucht", "stumm", "eisig", 
"taub", "steif", "weich", "leise", "kalt", "fein", "laut", "warm", 
"still"), group = c("H", "H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "V", "V", "V", 
"H", "V", "V", "H", "V", "A", "H", "V", "H", "V", "A", "V", "A", 
"V", "H", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "A", "H", "V", "V", "V", 
"H", "V", "A", "V", "H", "H", "A", "H", "A", "H", "H", "A", "H", 
"H", "A", "H", "A"), length = c(9L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 
7L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), frequency = c(1.114, 
1.519, 1.176, 0.903, 1.079, 0.903, 2.328, 2.305, 2.255, 1.716, 
2.199, 1.944, 1.505, 1.724, 1.146, 1.176, 1.699, 1.255, 1.633, 
1.204, 1.591, 1.23, 1.531, 1.041, 1.447, 1.041, 1.041, 1.477, 
1.531, 1.544, 1.845, 3.72, 1, 0.903, 0.699, 1.756, 0.301, 1.982, 
0.301, 0.477, 2.241, 2.064, 1.431, 2.718, 2.236, 2.651, 2.877, 
3.311, 2.838, 3.333, 2.937, 3.435)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))
```

Now I need to select subsamples of 5 items from each of the groups (A, V and H) so that differences in length and frequency between these 3 new subsamples were as small as possible, ideally not statistically significant. I usually do this manually and it takes a lot of time, but is there any way to automatize this process? Thank you for any hints/ideas.

Comment: A brute force option: what about doing random sampling repeatedly and choosing the sample with the lowest differences? The more random samples you generate the closer this will be to optimal.

Comment: thank you, I thought about this approach as well, but was hoping that there is some more elegant solution...

Comment: well - why not just multiplying length with frequency? the resulting column (lets call it choice), paired with the group column, selected for numbers near the mean of the new choice column (so that enough group variables are included) works well enough (meaning the t.test shows non-significance) - provided i didn't missunderstand your question.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how multiplying length and freq should work: these are two very different variables and I need to control both simultaneously. There might be very long words with low freq or very short words with high freq, but when multiplying these will become similar - this does not make sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that there is a special R package for solving this problem (LexOPS):
https://jackedtaylor.github.io/LexOPSdocs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a non-elegant brute force method as suggested above by Andy Eggers would be to select random samples until the condition is met, something like:

```
cycle = 1

repeat {
  
  print(cycle)
  cycle = cycle+1
  
  subsample = mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% slice_sample(n = 5) ## how many items should be selected from each group
  
  res.aov.freq <- aov(frequency ~ group, data = subsample)
  res.aov.freq.p = anova(res.aov.freq)$"Pr(>F)"[1] ## save ANOVA p-value for frequency
  
  res.aov.len <- aov(length ~ group, data = subsample)
  res.aov.len.p = anova(res.aov.len)$"Pr(>F)"[1] ## save ANOVA p-value for length
  
  cond = (res.aov.freq.p > .05)&
    (res.aov.len.p > .05) ## set required p-values for both variables

  if ((cond == TRUE)|
      (cycle == 1000)){ ## after how many cycles the script should stop if no solution found
    
    break
    
  }
}
```